# In meteor, is there a onRendered function for all templates?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

In meteor, is there a onRendered function for all templates? Or is there an easy alternative?

Example:

```
Template.allTemplates.onRendered(function(){/*doSomething()*/});
```

Rather than:

```
Template.template0.onRendered(function(){/*doSomething()*/});
Template.template1.onRendered(function(){/*doSomething()*/});
Template.template2.onRendered(function(){/*doSomething()*/});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the answer is right in front of you:

```
_.each(_.keys(Template), function(key) { 
     if (Template[key] instanceof Blaze.Template) { 
        console.log(key, "is the name of a template");
        Template[key].onRendered(myGlobalOnRenderFunction);
     }
});
```

I wouldn't recommend it though. It seems hard to predict what will happen in this case, because this will trigger for nested template as well, so you may get a lot more calls to that handler than you may wish.